# PHP Array value to css style

Tags: php, css, arrays, charts, styles

I am making a horizontal bar chart. I want to make the width of the bar equal to an array value (the array is an array_count_value array) The array looks like this (array name is: $countValue):

`Array ( [23] => 1 [2] => 4 [19] => 20 [18] => 21 [17] => 86 [16] => 108 [15] => 104 [14] => 102 [13] => 98 [12] => 117 [11] => 101 [1] => 86 [9] => 83 [8] => 36 )`

I want the bar width to be something like this:

```
.barWidth { width: <?php echo $countValue[23]."px"; ?>;
```

Comment: External css files are usually not parsed by the PHP interpreter, I guess that is your problem and not the code itself?!

Comment: I fixed in the inline style thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**Your Solution:**
use like bellow.
not in style file.

```
<div style="width: <?php echo $countValue[23]."px"; ?>" class="class">
    <!-- your code -->
</div>
```